# Unsound implicit cast warning not shown for generic parameter

Tags: dart, static-analysis

Is it bug, or some reasonable behaviour, that in strong mode this code

```
  Set<Set<int>> ssi() => ssd();
  Set<Set<dynamic>> ssd() => new Set.from(new Set.from(["string"]));
```

works fine, but this

```
  Set<int> si() => sd();
  Set<dynamic> sd() => new Set.from(["string"]);
```

produces `WARNING: Unsound implicit cast from Set<dynamic> to Set<int>`?

Comment: Maybe the power of the analyzer is not enough to perform such kind of operation (the deep parameter type analysis)?

Comment: @mezoni if it is so and no more reasons, it looks like a bug for me. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27954

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```yml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

To `.analysis_options` results in

[image]

Comment: If there wasn't a change recently that I missed then these two options need to be explicitly disabled like shown in the docs.